# PyQt Collection of QLineEdit objects

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlineedit

Is there some way in PyQt to get a collection of all `QLineEdit` objects?

I am trying to add a reset button that will blank out all text in all `QLineEdit` on a form, so I am looking for a way to loop through all `QLineEdit` objects rather than listing them all in my reset function that will connect to the reset button.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not store them in a `dict` or a `list` to begin with?

Comment: I might, but that winds up creating both the work of listing all of them and the brittleness of having them all listed (I then have one more place to update if I ever rename, delete, or add a field).  Programmatically getting the list should produce shorter, more maintainable code.

Comment: Actually I was talking about using a dict instead of the variables, not a dict in addition to the variables. More like `self.edits["some_name"] = QtGui.QLineEdit()` instead of `self.some_name = QtGui.QLineEdit()`. That should introduce very little change at the logic, if any.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, and might be a good way to go if I was writing all of the GUI by hand, but I am using the QT Designer to do the bulk of the GUI design and then doing some small fine tuning and putting in the actual program logic by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the line-edits have a parent, you could use:

```
for child in parent.findChildren(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    child.clear()
```

Or possibly:

```
for widget in qApp.allWidgets():
    if isinstance(widget, QtGui.QLineEdit):
        widget.clear()
```

Comment: the second one is exactly what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: I am asking this after almost 2 years, but what to do if I only want to clear widgets of one particular window? this will clear out *all* line edits, right? which one is line-edits' parent? the `QWindow` subclass? Sorry, I have just started and I am sort of lost.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti It really depends on how your application is structured. You should ask a new question and show your code.